# Process finished exit code PyCharm, while code works. R programming

Tags: r, crash, pycharm, exit-code

I am coding R in PyCharm, however, I repeatedly get the following exit code while running my code: *Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)*

My code works, I just tested it in the R interpreter, I have no idea why my code just doesn't run flawlessly in Pycharm. I get exit codes time after time in Pycharm while I am quite sure there's nothing wrong in my code (since it's literally a few calculations).

Could this be an IDE problem, and if so, how can I solve this?

Thank you in advance